# Last Modified in Document Library

Tags: document-library

When a folder is modified in a Document Library, Last Modified is shown correctly however when a file is modified within a folder, Last Modified does not change.

Is there a solution to this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you change a file inside a folder, modified timestamp of the file will change but the modified timestamp for the folder will not.
If you need any workaround you may visit this thread
[Change Document Library folder's Modified timestamp to latest timestamp inside](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/37246/change-document-library-folders-modified-timestamp-to-latest-timestamp-inside)

Answer (score 2):

I agree with Diptarag and you can check these out too, will explain alot:

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-GB/sharepointgeneral/thread/d80f5023-51cf-46ee-9e2f-6d1a1290f564

and

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-GB/sharepointgeneral/thread/d80f5023-51cf-46ee-9e2f-6d1a1290f564

Comment: Please include some summary content from the link to make this a better answer.