# Document library folder modified date update

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, document-library

I have a document library, and a folder inside it.

When i modified a document inside that folder or add a new document to that folder, the modified date of the folder should change(update).

Originally it wont change as i am not making and changes to the folder but

Is there any simple way to achieve this?

Comment: Related: [Change Document Library folder's Modified timestamp to latest timestamp inside](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/37246/change-document-library-folders-modified-timestamp-to-latest-timestamp-inside)

Comment: That is a powershell code, which iterate all the items in the doc lib, i am having 45k items in it, which takes ages to complete that, and resource intensive too, below workflow approach seems more realistic as it confines to only that object.

Comment: Yup, as said, it's only a related - but also indicating that it's also doable. There's also a guide for 2010 where Document Sets are used. I'd imagine it could be altered to folder-based structure and won't differ with 2013.  https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/23012.sharepoint-2010-how-to-update-parent-folders-timestamps-when-child-contents-have-been-modified.aspx

Answer (score 1):

A simple hack could be to add a separate column (custom_modified_date)  to the document library and whenever a file is added/updated execute a workflow (Microsoft Flow if you are using SharePoint online) and update the date in your custom modified date column.

Comment: I am a pure administrator, can you give me any relavent links to build such kind of workflow?

Comment: are you using sharepoint on-premise or sharepoint online ?

Comment: I am using On prem

Comment: You can build a SharePoint designer workflow on the document library. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/creating-a-workflow-by-using-sharepoint-designer-and-the-sharepoint-wo